# pygame shooting script causing lines

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, topdown

I have this very basic shooting script made in pygame. The script works fine and the bullets move as intended, but when bullets are fired off the left side of the screen specifically, their image is streeched across the screen, creating a line that follows the bullet.

```py
import pygame, math
pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius

    def draw(self, display):
        pygame.draw.circle(display, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self. y), self.radius)

class Bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, mouse_x, mouse_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.mouse_x = mouse_x
        self.mouse_y = mouse_y
        self.lifetime = 50
        self.speed = 15
        self.angle = math.atan2(mouse_y-self.y, mouse_x-self.x)
        self.x_vel = math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.y_vel = math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        
    def draw(self, draw):
        self.x += int(self.x_vel)
        self.y += int(self.y_vel)

        pygame.draw.circle(display, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y), 5)
        self.lifetime-= 1


player = Player(100,100,20)
bullets = []

run = True
#mainloop
while run:
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                bullets.append(Bullet(player.x, player. y, x, y))


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.y += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += 5
    
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.lifetime <= 0:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        bullet.draw(display)
    player.draw(display)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I can't find a reason this could be happening, so I'm forced to make bullets disappear when off-screen.

Comment: You have to clear the display or draw the background in every frame.

Comment: @Rabbid76 OP is clearing the screen "display.fill((0,0,0))"

Comment: This is a bug in a recent version of pygame. You can fix it by using `pygame-ce` instead, a better maintained fork of pygame. The patch specifically that fixes what you're facing: https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/pull/2032

Comment: To install pygame-ce, first `pip uninstall pygame` then `pip install pygame-ce`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in a recent version of pygame. You can fix it by using pygame-ce instead, a better maintained fork of pygame. The patch specifically that fixes what you're facing: https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/pull/2032